# Impossible Minesweeper?

Tags: probability, solvability, minesweeper

I was playing the game Minesweeper earlier today and came across the following situation:

[image: Stalemate? Minesweeper Arrangement]

(Look at the bottom-middle section of the gameboard.)

It seems to me that either of the two diagonal pathways (for mines within the open square) could potentially work as a plausible choice... Is there a strategy, or at this point would it just become a 50% guessing game?

Comment: It's just a 50/50 guess. The original game and most clones will have these, though some will reject them so that the player never encounters them.

Comment: @DanielMathias I figured, just wanted some confirmation from y'all... unfortunate though.

Comment: This one: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/js/mines.html guarantees to avoid guessing situations.

Comment: I used to get these a lot in the app on my phone. I got to where I would try to find them as early in my solve as I could and then make my guess as soon as I was sure it was 50/50 so I didn't feel like I wasted a whole game only to lose on a guess.